# Getting a 401 response while using Requests package

Tags: python, python-requests, http-error

I am trying to access a server over my internal network under `https://prodserver.de/info`.
I have the code structure as below:

```
import requests
from requests.auth import *

username = 'User'
password = 'Hello@123'
resp = requests.get('https://prodserver.de/info/', auth=HTTPBasicAuth(username,password))
print(resp.status_code)
```

While trying to access this server via browser, it works perfectly fine.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `HTTPBasicAuth` uses `latin1` to encode your credentials; does your server expect UTF-8-encoded credentials instead?

Answer (score 0):

try using requests' generic auth, like this:

```
resp = requests.get('https://prodserver.de/info/', auth=(username,password)
```

Comment: Trired, was not successful

Answer (score 0):

> What am I doing wrong?

I can not be sure without investigating your server, but I suggest checking if assumption (you have made) that server is using *Basic authorization*, there exist various [Authentication schemes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Authentication#authentication_schemes), it is also possible that your server use cookie-based solution, rather than headers-based one.

> While trying to access this server via browser, it works perfectly
> fine.

You might then use developer tools to see what is actually send inside and with request which does result in success.